# Uploading Data from a CSV file to a Google Cloud SQL Instance using Python in Pycharm

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, pycharm, data-science

I am having trouble figuring out how to upload data from a CSV file to an SQL instance on Google Cloud. The scope of my project right now is to collect data from a website, import it into a CSV file, and then upload the data from the CSV file into my Cloud SQL instance, all automated by Python. My IDE where I write my code in is in Pycharm, so I was wondering if it's possible to have Python handle everything- are there any necessary Python libraries that I have to import?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do all of this in python. There's 3 things to do here.

1. Use a package to get the data from 'a website'. Depending on the website, just using the requests package might be enough. Otherwise you might need to dip into a more 'complicated' package like [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).
2. Using the method above you'll need to put this in a CSV file. I'm not sure why you would want to use a CSV file as an intermediary here, but there's a ton of tutorials on handling CSV files.
3. Use a SQL package to read/write to the Cloud SQL instance. The [w3 page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp) for MySQL is a good starting point.

Also, read up on how to connect from whereever you're running your code to a Cloud SQL instance. I very strongly advise to use the Cloud SQL proxy as described in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview).